# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'addressbar' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded

```
private void browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        addressbar.Text = browser.Address;
    }
```

I have no idea why this is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple threads (UI thread and others), this problem will happen when you want to manipulate an object from a thread, and that object is created by another thread.
You must use Invoke Method:

```
private void browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    
    changeAddressBar(browser.Address)
}

void changeAddressBar(string txt){
     if (addressbar.InvokeRequired)
            addressbar.Invoke(new Action<string>(changeAddressBar), txt);
        else
            addressbar.Text= txt;
}
```

Comment: Please explain it